# Localização GPS retorna somente null (0.0,0.0)

Tags: java, android, geolocalização, gps

Tenho uma aplicação para dispositivos Android, com vários endereços. Ao clicar em algum endereço, queria pegar a localização atual do usuário e jogar no *link* do google maps `http://maps.google.com/maps?&saddr="`, juntamente com as coordenadas do destino.

Porém, os resultados de "latitude" e "longitude" atuais somente retornam "0.0".

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
public class Guaruja extends Activity implements LocationListener {

Button bttela2;
TextView TextView1;
TextView t1;
Uri uri;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    protected Context context;
String provider;
double latitude, longitude;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.guaruja);



    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);


    TextView1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TextView1);



    TextView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            String lati = String.valueOf(latitude);
            String longi = String.valueOf(longitude);
            String firt = "http://maps.google.com/maps?&saddr=";
            String secord="&daddr=-23.990624, -46.282269";
            String virgula=",";
            String url= firt+lati+virgula+longi+secord;
               uri=Uri.parse(url);
               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
               startActivity(intent);
        }


    });



}


public void onLocationChanged(Location location){

  if(location!= null){
       latitude = location.getLatitude() * 1E6;
       longitude = location.getLongitude() * 1E6;

}
    }
```

EDITADO

---

Eu fiquei vários dias "empacado" nesse código, pois sempre a localização me retornava 0,0 e me jogava no oceano Pacífico.
Eu consegui resolver, apesar de não usar o código de localização em si. 
Como podem perceber no código a cima, eu utilizei a URL do Google Maps para levar o usuário até o mapa com as coordenadas definidas por mim. Após uma pesquisa sobre essa URL, encontrei uma solução que funcionou muito bem para mim, usei o link assim: "http://maps.google.com/maps?&saddr=&daddr=-23.990624,-46.282269&sensor=TRUE", ou seja, apenas deixei as coordenadas de partida em branco ("&saddr=").

Agradeço a todos pela ajuda.

Comment: Está testando num dispositivo real ou no emulador/VM?

Comment: Em um dispositivo real. Obrigado.

Comment: Testando o Google Maps, ele funciona no dispositivo? Testou em outro?

Comment: O google maps funciona normal para achar minha localização. Testei em outro device, o resultado também é null.

Comment: Houve algum progresso? Poderia incluir quais permissões de `Location` esta usando?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

Comment: De uma olhada na resposta dada nessa pergunta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188105/locationmanagers-location-in-android-returns-null. O autor da resposta sugere usar outro provider (network) dado que o gps não retorna dados.

Comment: Eu editei meu post com o código que funcionou perfeitamente para o que eu precisava. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @user3825655 Posta tua solução como resposta e marca ela como solução :)

Comment: Fiz isso, obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu fiquei vários dias "empacado" nesse código, pois sempre a localização me retornava 0,0 e me jogava no oceano Pacífico. Eu consegui resolver, apesar de não usar o código de localização em si. Como podem perceber no código a cima, eu utilizei a URL do Google Maps para levar o usuário até o mapa com as coordenadas definidas por mim. Após uma pesquisa sobre essa URL, encontrei uma solução que funcionou muito bem para mim, usei o link assim: "http://maps.google.com/maps?&saddr=&daddr=-23.990624,-46.282269&sensor=TRUE", ou seja, apenas deixei as coordenadas de partida em branco ("&saddr=").

Agradeço a todos pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa esperar o GPS calibrar. Cria uma estrutura de loading que lhe alerta após o `onLocationChanged(Location location)` for diferente de null. Exemplo:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){


    if(location!= null){
       latitude = location.getLatitude()*1E6;
       longitude = location.getLongitude()*1E6;
       dialog.dismiss();// Aqui você fecha o dialog. O gps foi calibrado
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Douglas. Mas ainda que eu coloque o "if", o retorno ainda é "0.0" tanto para latitude quanto para longitude. O que é estranho, pois a condição do "if" é para quando "location" for diferente de null. Consegue ver algum problema no meu código?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Douglas. Mas ainda que eu coloque o "if", o retorno ainda é "0.0" tanto para latitude quanto para longitude. O que é estranho, pois a condição do "if" é para quando "location" for diferente de null. Consegue ver algum problema no meu código?

Comment: Eu não vejo a implementacao da LocationListener na classe `Guaruja.java` Talvez o problema seja esse. Esse exemplo funciona perfeitamente :D http://javapapers.com/android/get-current-location-in-android/

Comment: Eu já tentei usar "LocationListener" de varias formas, inclusive igual a do exemplo que me enviou, porém me retorna um erro na expressão "this". Estou a 2 dias nessa luta :s. Eu já programava para iPhone (ObjectiveC), mas não tenho muita experiencia com java. Obrigado pela ajuda amigo.

Comment: Cara, se tu conseguir mostrar a classe que esta dando o erro talvez eu consiga ajudar mais. vlw

Comment: Olá Douglas, eu editei meu código em minha pergunta. Não está mais dando erro, mas continua a retornar null. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Faz um teste, liga o Google Maps mexe nele até ele achar tua localização... depois disso, testa tua aplicação e ver se ainda ta retornando null.

Comment: Feito. No google maps, achei minha localização normalmente. Mas na minha aplicação ainda retorna null.

Comment: Eu editei meu post com o código que funcionou perfeitamente para o que eu precisava. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, this); deixa assim que vai melhorar muito sua aplicação.